# Why does readline-sync exit the node shell when it returns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm having the following issue with the npm package `readline-sync`:

```
const ask = require('readline-sync');

const answer = ask.question('Why does this exit the node shell?');

console.log(answer);
```

In the preceding code block the `console.log` statement will not run because after the user answers the question and hits return they are returned to the command line. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I'm running macOS high sierra and node 10.11.0

Comment: your `console.lg()` uses `answers` but the variable you declare is `answer`.

Comment: Your code works fine if you fix the typo.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo! I'll fix it in the question but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It absolutely works for me in Node 10.11.0, but I'm on Ubuntu not MacOS.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling it's something weird about my environment but I can't think of what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about the inclusion of readline-sync here. The node process will exit at the end of any script, like this:

```
const x = 3;
console.log(x);
```

We'll see "3" logged to the console and the process will return the user to the command line.